# Passing date from javascript to json http post method format changed to 0001-01-01T00:00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime, http-post

I am debugging .js file in firefox browser,

My code is this,

```
 function getReport(searchCriteria, page, pageSize, sortBy, sortingDirection) {
            return $http.post(fullPath + '/Evaluations/GetPerformanceReport', searchCriteria, { params: { page: page, pageSize: pageSize, sortBy: sortBy, sortingDirection: sortingDirection } }
                );
        }
```

In above method i have searchCriteria has one parameter From date "2018-10-10" and To date is "2019-01-01"  In Controler i am getting this value "{0001-01-01T00:00:00}" for both dates.

Controller Method getting data from script is like,

```
   public JsonResult GetReport(ReportSearch searchCriteria, int page, int pageSize,
            string sortBy, string sortingDirection)
        {}
```

Here ReportSearch  is class having attributes,

```
Public class ReportSearch  
{
public DateTime From { get; set; }
public DateTime To{ get; set; }
}
```

I dont understand why it is changing "2018-10-10" date format to "0001-01-01T00:00:00" ?

EDITED:

In js function i have actually

```
function getReport($scope.searchCriteria, ($scope.page * $scope.pageSize), $scope.pageSize, $scope.sortBy, $scope.sortingDirection) {
            return $http.post(fullPath + '/Evaluations/GetPerformanceReport', searchCriteria, { params: { page: page, pageSize: pageSize, sortBy: sortBy, sortingDirection: sortingDirection } }
                );
        }
```

In $scope.searchCriteria get while debbuging i have value like From:"2018-10-10" To:"2019-01-01". In controller i am getting this value and model where i am getting "ReportSearch" class mentioned above. in controller i am getting date like this "0001-01-01T00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not format, it's data loss. The date in the controller, '0001-01-01T00:00:00', is just 0 formatted as a date.

This seems to be a poblem of binding the post. What server platform are you using? It looks like C#? With MVC or Web Api? Your model has to exactly match the structure of the post. If you can, use a nullable datetime in the binding model. 0 dates are a pain. It looks to me like you need to, in the javascript, group all of your arguments together into JSON object, then, on the server, modify your binding model to exactly reflect the structure of this object.

Comment: yes these are dates that i am sending i mentioned in my post not empty

Comment: Well then could you put the body of the post, copied from dev tools, into the question please, along with the binding model? That might help.

Comment: yes i am using MVC with web api Sorry i dont understand binding model ?

Comment: The docs on parameter binding are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) You should be looking at the [FromBody] tag and making sure the class that you use for binding corresponds to the structure of your post.